# Establish relationship among nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j. I have customer and product data into Neo4j. While loading I have not established any relationship among them. Now I want to establish relation among them like:

```
create (Customer1)-[:bought]->(Item1),(Customer1)-[:bought]->(Item2);
```

After I execute this statement it says Relationship established but as and when I try to access it like:

```
start n=node(*) match (n)-[:bought]->(items) where n.NodeName! = "Customer1" return items;
```

it says 0 rows. I think if it successfully establishes relationship it should give me 2 items, Item1 & Item2.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you didn't set `NodeName` for your `Customer1` node in your creation query. Try to modify it like this:

```
create (Customer1 { NodeName:'Customer1' }), (Item1 { NodeName:'Item1' }), (Item2 { NodeName:'Item2' }), (Customer1)-[:bought]->(Item1), (Customer1)-[:bought]->(Item2);
```

Then your second query should return 2 rows as you expected.

**Update:**
Ok, I didn't understand the question correctly. So, you want to establish a relationship between already existing nodes. Then try this:

```
start Customer1=node:node_auto_index(NodeName='Customer1'), Item1=node:node_auto_index(NodeName='Item1'), Item2=node:node_auto_index(NodeName='Item2')
create (Customer1)-[:bought]->(Item1),(Customer1)-[:bought]->(Item2);
```

Comment: Correct.. But the nodes Customer1, Item1, Item2 are already created. Now I just want to establish relationship among them.

Comment: Perfect..! Worked. Thanks!